# Want to change Region Name in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hlw guys, i want to change oracle apex region name which will be dynamic. Suppose when we create a new region by default its name NEW. i want to replace this name to current month of sysdate. for better under standing please see the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- create a hidden item, let's suppose its name is `P1_REGION_TITLE`
- set its source to

  - expression
  - `to_char(sysdate, 'mm.yyyy')`
- set region's name to reflect value of that item, literally `&P1_REGION_TITLE.`

  - pay attention to leading ampersand `&` and leading dot `.`

That's all.